# Element web-app must be declared error in Intellij

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, web-applications

I work in a project that I have a `logback-test.xml` file and the file shows error. It's a multi-module maven project and the file mentioned is provided below,

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

  <configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
      <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%t] %-5p %c:%L - %m%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="com.ratepay" level="ERROR"/>

    <root level="ERROR">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
  </configuration>
</web-app>
```

When I hold the cursor atop of the `web-app` tag, I get the error as `Element web-app must be declared`. My colleague use the `Eclipse` and he doesn't have the same error.

I have seen a few answers for the issue, but, can anyone clearly explain why does it see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following portion for logback.xml from the beginning.

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
```

Remove the following portion from the last.

```
</web-app>
```

It is not a web.xml which is deployment descriptor. logback.xml and web.xml are aparently different.

In case of logback.xml, the final structure should be like this given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
      <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%t] %-5p %c:%L - %m%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="com.ratepay" level="ERROR"/>

    <root level="ERROR">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Ok, it seems the error goes away. I will accept the answer after 7 minutes.